# Write a regex that matches with string separated by dash but should be all upper case or lower case

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a regex that checks for the strings like

*ju-NIP-er-us skop-u-LO-rum* and *ui-LA-ui LO-iu-yu*

the set of characters separated by the   *-*

this is what I have got

```js
let str = "ju-NIP-er-us skop-u-LO-rum";
let str2 = "jU-NiP-Er-us skop-u-LO-rum"
console.log(/^\p{L}+(?:[- ']\p{L}+)*$/u.test(str)) // this matches
console.log(/^\p{L}+(?:[- ']\p{L}+)*$/u.test(str2)) // this also matches but this shouldn't match
```

The problem is set of characters separated by the - should either be all capital or all smaller ,but right now it is matching the mix characters as well ,see the snippet .How to make this regex match only all small or all caps between dashes.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex to make sure to match same case substrings between `-` or space or `'` delimiters:

```bash
^(?:\p{Lu}+|\p{Ll}+)(?:[- '](?:\p{Lu}+|\p{Ll}+))*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BNcgYI/1)

Non-capturing group `(?:\p{Lu}+|\p{Ll}+)` matches either 1+ of uppercase unicode letters or 1+ of lowercase unicode letters but not a mix of both cases.